# JAR run and works fine in local ubuntu:16.04 but can't run same env in docker

Tags: java, postgresql, docker

I have a java script that

1. reads data from a Data/files.txt
2. store the Data/files.txt into the postgres
3. Once stored successfully it will move files under data to another folder Move/files.txt

Tree is

```
App.jar
Data/files.txt
Move
```

Scenario:

1. Locally. Install postgres in host and run the jar in host it stores in postgres and moves to the target folder
2. If I run it in docker it doesn't' work, but only shows the postgres database connected successfully

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

CMD ["java", "-jar", "cdrt.jar"]
```

I run docker-compose for them

```
postgres
pgadmin 
java-console
```

`java-console` mount in my host under users directory to `/usr/src/myapp`

I reside all 3

1. App.jar
2. Date/files
3. Move

Could anyone help me on this?

docker-compose logs -f java

```
java-console | Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.
java-console | timer alrady set
java-console | ERROR: could not open file "/home/app/doc/kyc/kyc_sample.txt" for reading: No such file or directory
java-console |   Hint: COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
java-console |   Where: SQL statement "COPY cdr_kYC ( 
java-console |   CUSTOMER_PROFILE_ID ,
java-console |  msisdn ,
java-console |  NATIONAL_ID  ,
java-console |  CUSTOMER_NAME ,
java-console |  GENDER  ,
java-console |  DATE_OF_BIRTH ,
java-console |  TRANSACTION_ID  ,
java-console |  PERMANENT_DISTRICT  ,
java-console |  PERMANENT_THANA  ,
java-console |  PERMANENT_ADDRESS ,
java-console |  PRESENT_DISTRICT,
java-console |  PRESENT_THANA  ,
java-console |  PRESENT_ADDRESS  ,
java-console |  CUSTOMER_EMAIL,
java-console |  ENTRY_TYPE ,
java-console |  SUBMIT_TIME ,
java-console |  VERSION_TYPE 
java-console |      ) FROM '/home/app/doc/kyc/kyc_sample.txt'DELIMITER '|' CSV  HEADER"
java-console | PL/pgSQL function cdr_kyc_record(text) line 31 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having?  Can you show a relevant fragment of the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: (Given the heavy emphasis on local files this task might be easier to run outside of Docker, even if the database itself is in a container.)

Comment: `it doesn't' work`. What error do you get?

Comment: could you share us the docker logs result?

Comment: Please check the logs added in my post. What else would you require?

Comment: I resolved it on my end. Thanks anyway